# how to post message on facebook wall using python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post message on facebook wall using python. I got an Access token from developer Apps. I tried to use the below code

```
 graph = facebook.GraphAPI(Access token)
 profile = graph.get_object('me')
 graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="Hi Good Afternoon Have a nice day!")
```

I can't able to access the permission.Am getting error like

```
 **"facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"**
```

Is anything to change settings in developer Apps. I don't kow how to do that.Plz help me to learn it.I referred some links to do this but am not getting any solutions. Plz findout the way to do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you selected the publish_action in extended permissions tab while you generated the access token you have

[image]

Also verify this by using Graph API Explorer